# How to modify array value using foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, foreach

I'm trying to modify value inside the array using foreach loop here is the array content

```
folders: [{id: "4", sysUser_id: "1", department_id: "0", foldername: "Auditors Files", parent_id: "0"},…]

0: {id: "4", sysUser_id: "1", department_id: "0", foldername: "Auditors Files", parent_id: "0"}
    department_id: "0"
    foldername: "Auditors Files"
    id: "4"
    parent_id: "0"
    sysUser_id: "1"
1: {id: "3", sysUser_id: "1", department_id: "0", foldername: "Computer Components", parent_id: "0"}
    department_id: "0"
    foldername: "Computer Components"
    id: "3"
    parent_id: "0"
    sysUser_id: "1"
2: {id: "2", sysUser_id: "1", department_id: "0", foldername: "Internal Auditors", parent_id: "0"}
    department_id: "0"
    foldername: "Internal Auditors"
    id: "2"
    parent_id: "0"
    sysUser_id: "1"
3: {id: "1", sysUser_id: "1", department_id: "0", foldername: "IT Audit", parent_id: "0"}
    department_id: "0"
    foldername: "IT Audit"
    id: "1"
    parent_id: "0"
    sysUser_id: "1"
```

what Im trying to do is modify all the id value like this:

```
$reconstruct = array();
foreach($result['folders'] as $folder){
   $reconstruct['id'][] = $this->my_encryption->urlEncrypt($folder->id);
   $reconstruct['sysUser_id'][] = $this->my_encryption->urlEncrypt($folder->sysUser_id);
   $reconstruct['department_id'][] = $this->my_encryption->urlEncrypt($folder->department_id);
   $reconstruct['foldername'][] = $folder->foldername;
   $reconstruct['parent_id'][] = $this->my_encryption->urlEncrypt($folder->parent_id);
}
$try['folders'] = $reconstruct;
echo json_encode($try);
```

But the output becoming like this

```
folders: {id: ["OElkUTBtK3FLZElwZm52ekhoSnZudz09OjpZBMuJMlf1iSHwxTeJncvP",…],…}
  department_id: ["OE1Gb0xDK3BzNllzMjltVTVEZ3VwQT09OjoKbrlVvBKoPd5GiomYTreX",…]
    0: "OE1Gb0xDK3BzNllzMjltVTVEZ3VwQT09OjoKbrlVvBKoPd5GiomYTreX"
    1: "N3ZnK1V4MFZlckNFa0NzMytIREt1Zz09OjqzdSvYf1H6z21oWM_g2f8K"
    2: "eUdkYmxHKzZkSmlsbEZXL2c0K250QT09OjoSE0DgI8sd2ho9JWDAsaSw"
    3: "cXM5WlpqcjdjS0VncFNWOVJreUNrZz09OjrC-NAeGAPthrfrH-SG9sx8"
  foldername: ["Auditors Files", "Computer Components", "Internal Auditors", "IT Audit"]
    0: "Auditors Files"
    1: "Computer Components"
    2: "Internal Auditors"
    3: "IT Audit"
  id: ["OElkUTBtK3FLZElwZm52ekhoSnZudz09OjpZBMuJMlf1iSHwxTeJncvP",…]
    0: "OElkUTBtK3FLZElwZm52ekhoSnZudz09OjpZBMuJMlf1iSHwxTeJncvP"
    1: "Vlh4NVZmQlQxNjRSUWpsclc4SUtwZz09OjpwQRLcA_b90a8QT6mc4vxN"
    2: "VGZwVlBrcmdEVUQzMzFMby9vdVQvdz09Ojrwdaqei86MQsuNRn-SOAYR"
    3: "ZXlSUmNKRFMvWFFSRW90T240WEovUT09OjotEXan6A0ZO3lUBW0ae-N3"
  parent_id: ["cXUvcWRtM0xKM2lSdXR3dTB2bkkvZz09Ojq7vtCUxphCBQya72IILSOO",…]
    0: "cXUvcWRtM0xKM2lSdXR3dTB2bkkvZz09Ojq7vtCUxphCBQya72IILSOO"
    1: "WFlvemlZcm1oT2ZTTy9sVUJLbzlyZz09OjpYmqeY8CWXnmn-l1sqMxHq"
    2: "c2FHUmIrZ1J5OGpDT01hRFlxOVJVdz09OjpOa5sIP8BGWJpy9ZmA2ZUI"
    3: "S1YyRHc1WWlMKzZMaTBQbUc0NmxkZz09OjqYj_cEXN1s75Vwimy9GZ6j"
  sysUser_id: ["UjIxZ1hMR3dvd3BISVpnNjVkVk9tdz09OjrUK5qhxu0Mp4vvTN5YA4Eo",…]
    0: "UjIxZ1hMR3dvd3BISVpnNjVkVk9tdz09OjrUK5qhxu0Mp4vvTN5YA4Eo"
    1: "UGRwb0RYRUd5N3BrVTV0VDUrS0tkdz09OjpQo2CVXk28hUGGfrBVScq7"
    2: "V3hXWGhoRWRyT01oQjdwV3hsUFVPZz09OjoxHbsRPJhSLQBEJKoBTAgB"
    3: "cUd1UDRDR1VMZmh1d2tsU0FQaXlUQT09Ojq57rc7RIQMOaKN3NQfVGVa"
```

All I want is to change the array value and still have the same format. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you please describe the expected outcome? You don't appear to be changing anything; instead, you're creating a new array with keys like id, department id, and so on. Given your code, the structure of the output array is correct - `$reconstruct['id'][]` If you want to modify something, why not do it in the same array rather than creating a new one?

Comment: I want to get the same output as is. Or you can see it at the top the very first code I posted. And also I am using codeigniter Im just returning the array that's why I cannot change it in the same array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the desired array structure, create a new array within the for loop, add the keys and values to it, and then push the new array to $reconstruct. I hope the following code is useful -

```
<?php

$reconstruct = [];
foreach ($result['folders'] as $folder) {
    $updated_folder = [];
    $updated_folder['id'] = $this->my_encryption->urlEncrypt($folder->id);
    $updated_folder['sysUser_id'] = $this->my_encryption->urlEncrypt($folder->sysUser_id);
    $updated_folder['department_id'] = $this->my_encryption->urlEncrypt($folder->department_id);
    $updated_folder['foldername'] = $folder->foldername;
    $updated_folder['parent_id'] = $this->my_encryption->urlEncrypt($folder->parent_id);
    $reconstruct[] = $updated_folder;
}
echo json_encode($reconstruct);
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're using, `$ArrayName[index][] = value`, is appending a value to the end of an array called `$ArrayName[index]`. What you want is to create a new array for each original array, something like this:

```
$reconstruct = array();
foreach($result['folders'] as $folder){
   $newArray = [];
   $newArray['id'] = $this->my_encryption->urlEncrypt($folder->id);
   $newArray['sysUser_id'] = $this->my_encryption->urlEncrypt($folder->sysUser_id);
   $newArray['department_id'] = $this->my_encryption->urlEncrypt($folder->department_id);
   $newArray['foldername'] = $folder->foldername;
   $newArray['parent_id'] = $this->my_encryption->urlEncrypt($folder->parent_id);

   $reconstruct[] = $newArray;
}
```